# java code that reads from file should read the full file but doesn't

Tags: java

Java code reads from file checks for words with curly brackets and then writes the words without curly brackets

The code works fine cause it reads the file and shows the words without brackets but its a huge file with four hundred lines but the result shows only few lines which means the code reads the file and writes the words without curly brackets but doesn't iterates through the full file

changed the regular espression but that is fine cause it reads any words with curly brackets and writes words without curly braces

code that worcs

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;

public class StringUtilitiesFromFile  {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
        {
                String Android = "Android is CS and (OS)";
                String OS = Android.replaceAll("\\(.*\\)", "");  
                System.out.println("Android " + OS);
       }
```

}

the result is Android Android is CS and doesn't prints (OS) which is with brackets

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;

public class StringUtilitiesFromFile  {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
        {
              File file = new File("Auth.html");
        String string = FileUtils.readFileToString(file);  
                String And = string.replaceAll("\\(.*\\)", "");  
        System.out.println(And);    
                System.out.println("");           
       }
}
```

the result is:
avenue
beard
beneath
boat
bound 
bright budget builder bulkhead businessman businessperson businesswoman butcher
cage carbon carbon
carcinogen card caution cautious
cave
characteristic
chief
chief clay
clean coach
coal
comfortable
consumer consumer goods
contact
cool courage
courage courageous course court cousin cover cruel
debate defend defendant defense defense defiance deficit
define

which are about twenty four lines but the actual file contains about four hundred lines

the file has the words
ability (noun) able (adjective) about (preposition) about (adverb) above (adverb) above (preposition) abroad (adverb) absence (noun) absent (adjective) absolute (adjective) abstract abstract (adjective) abuse (verb) abuse (noun) abusive academic (adjective) accept (verb) acceptable (adjective) acceptance access (verb) access (noun)accompany (verb) according+to (preposition) account (verb) account (noun) accountant accurate (adjective)a (indefinite article) abandon (verb) ability (noun) able (adjective) about (preposition) about (adverb) above (adverb) above (preposition) abroad (adverb) absence (noun) absent (adjective) absolute (adjective) abstract abstract (adjective) abuse (verb) abuse (noun) abusive academic (adjective) accept (verb) acceptable (adjective) acceptance access (verb) access (noun) accompany (verb) according+to (preposition) account (verb) account (noun) accountant accurate (adjective)accuse ache (noun) ache achieve (verb) acquire (verb) acquit across (adverb) across (preposition) act (verb) act (noun) action (noun) active activity (noun) actor actress actual (adjective) actually (adverb) adapt (verb) add (verb) addition (noun) additional (adjective) address (noun) address (verb) adequate (adjective) adjourn adjust (verb) administration (noun) admiration admire (verb) admission (noun)admit (verb) adopt (verb) adoption adult (noun) adult (adjective) advance (noun) advance (verb) advantage (noun) adventure (noun) adventurous advertise (verb) advertisement (noun) advice advise (verb) affair (noun) affect (verb) affection affectionate afford (verb) afraid (adjective) after (adverb) after (conjunction) after (preposition) afternoon again (adverb) against (preposition) age (noun) age (verb) agency (noun) agent (noun)aggravation aggressive ago agree (verb) agreement (noun) agriculture ahead (adverb) aid (verb) aid (noun) aim (noun) aim (verb) air air traffic controller airplane (noun) airport (noun) aisle alarm (verb) alarm (noun) alert (noun) alert (adjective) alert (verb) alibi alimony alive (adjective) all (adverb) all (pronoun) all (adjective) all right (adverb) all right (adjective)

there are more lines;code should just read words without curly brackets and write

Comment: Please provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Also, where does `FileUtils.readFileToString` come from?

Comment: it is "org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;"            now you could try the code and c what it does    thancs

Comment: added more code which prints string without brackets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might be running into trouble with your regular expression.

You are trying to knock out all characters that match this: `\(.*\)`. The problem is that the characters "(" and ")" also match `.*`, so your expression matches `(` + *anything, including parentheses* + `)`, and this is likely taking out a whole swath of words you don't intend to remove.

One solution would be to use reluctant quantifiers instead of greedy quantifiers.
Use `*?` in place of `*` to achieve this. It will match the smallest amount of characters that fulfills your regular expression.
Another option would be to explicitly exclude parentheses in the regex, as in `\([^()]*\)`.

Try this:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;

public class StringUtilitiesFromFile  {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
        {
              File file = new File("Auth.html");
        String string = FileUtils.readFileToString(file);  
                String And = string.replaceAll("\\(.*?\\)", "");  
        System.out.println(And);    
                System.out.println("");           
       }
}
```

Go to a regular expression tester like [RegexPlanet](https://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html) to work out the kinks.

See the docs for [Greedy vs. Reluctant Quantifiers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/quant.html)